# Dispose writer after memoryStream

Tags: c#, stream, naudio

This is a piece of my code:

```
private static MemoryStream outputStream;


public static void ConvertMp3ToWavStream(string inputPath)
        {                           
            outputStream = new MemoryStream();
            using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(inputPath))
            {
                using (WaveStream waveStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader))
                {
                    WaveFileWriter waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(outputStream, waveStream.WaveFormat);

                    byte[] bytes = new byte[waveStream.Length];
                    waveStream.Position = 0;
                    waveStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)waveStream.Length);
                    waveFileWriter.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    waveFileWriter.Flush();                    
                }
            }                
        }
```

This is my `CloseAndDispose` method, which I invoke after some manipulations:

```
private static void CloseAndDispose()
        {
            if (outputStream != null)
            {
                outputStream.Close();
                outputStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

The problem: after all actions I've got some memory in memory stack, which wasn't disposed. As I understand, It's my `writer`. When I try to dispose writer, I get an exception. (can't read `MemoryStream`). When I try to close and dispose writer after `CloseAndDispose()` method, I get an exception. Where should I close `waveFileWriter`?

Comment: If it's this [WaveFileWriter](https://daisy-trac.cvsdude.com/urakawa-sdk/browser/trunk/csharp/audio/NAudio/Wave/WaveOutputs/WaveFileWriter.cs?rev=1346) you're a little stuck. *Some* `Stream` based classes allow you to construct them with a parameter which indicates whether the passed in stream should be `Disposed`, but this one doesn't appear to give you that option. Of course, if you're working with this source, you're free to change it to implement that option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NAudio has a helper class called `IgnoreDisposeStream` in the `NAudio.Utils` namespace. Wrap your memory stream in one of those before passing it into the `WaveFileWriter`

```
using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter(new IgnoreDisposeStream(outputStream),
                                       waveStream.WaveFormat))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a local `MemoryStream` to `WaveFileWriter` and copy it to the global one before it's disposed:

```
public static void ConvertMp3ToWavStream(string inputPath)
{                           
    outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    var outputStreamLocal = new MemoryStream();
    using (...
    {        
            using (var waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(outputStreamLocal, ...
            {
                ...
                outputStreamLocal.CopyTo(outputStream);
            }
    }
}
```